# Kendo Drawer component for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, drawer

I am following the official example of Kendo Drawer component for Angular. First, I declared the variable

```
public items: Array<DrawerItem> = [];
```

Next, in constructor I have the following lines

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
const routes: any[] = router.config;

routes.forEach(route => {
  this.items.push({
    text: route.text,
    path: route.path ? route.path : ''
  });
});
```

}

It says that *'path' does not exist in type DrawerItem*. Why? All Kendo examples are referencing to this property. 
Also, router does not contain the 'text' property. I cannot map routes with the Drawer component.

Thank you.

Comment: can you add any example link that use path property

Comment: @jitender [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/drawer/routing/)

Comment: check your import path for typos it should be `import { DrawerItem } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';` also can you please create stackblitz demo of your problem

Comment: @jitender Imports are fine. Stackblitz code is at [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6upjg)

Comment: @jitender The official DrawerItem doc is at [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/DrawerItem/). It seems that DrawerItem doesn't contain the 'path' property! Somehow the examples are outdated or I'm making mistakes in undarstanding :)

Comment: console.log(route) and see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use Kendo UI drawer with Angular router. If that's the case you could find more information and sample here:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/drawer/routing/

At this moment the the above link doesn't show the code sample so if that's the case use this one: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/drawer/how-to/hierarchical-drawer/